# How to parallelise python script for processing 10,000 files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, subprocess, python-multithreading

I have more than 10,000 `C` files, which i need to pass each one of them to some application `foo.exe` for processing and generating dis-assembly files for each one of the `C` files,i.e. at the end of this process i will have 10,000 `lst`/`output` files! Assuming that, this process is not **`IO-Bound`** (despite the fact that `foo.exe` Write new `lst` file to disk for each `c` file. is it right assumption ?).

**My task is**

To implement parallel python program to get the job done in minimum time! by utilizing all cpu cores for this task.

**My approach**

I have implemented this program and it works for me, the pseudo code listed below:

1. iterate over all `c` files and push the `abs path` for each one in a global `List`, `files_list`.
2. calculate the `cpu` logical cores number (with `psutil` py module), this will be the maximum threads to be dispatched later. lets assume it is **8** threads.
3. generate new list, `workers_list` (its a list of lists) which contains the intervals or indexes (L_index, R_index) yielded from division of `files_list` by **8** . e.g. if i have 800 c files then `workers_list` will look like this: `workers_list = [[0-99],[100,199],...,[700,799]]`.
4. dispatch 8 thread, `workers`, which each one will manipulate single entry in `workers_list`. each thread will open process (`subprocess.call(...)`) and call the `foo.exe` on the current `c` file.

posting the relevant code below:

**The relevant Code**

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import psutil
import threading
import os

class LstGenerator(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.elfdumpExePath = r"C:\.....\elfdump.exe" #abs path to the executable 
    self.output_dir = r"C:\.....\out"             #abs path to where i want the lst files to be generated
    self.files = [] # assuming that i have all the files in this list (abs path for each .C file)
  
  def slice(self, files):
    files_len = len(files)
    j = psutil.cpu_count()
    slice_step = files_len / j
    workers_list = []
    lhs = 0
    rhs = slice_step
    while j:
      workers_list.append(files[lhs:rhs])
      lhs += slice_step
      rhs += slice_step
      j -= 1
      if j == 1:  # last iteration
        workers_list.append(files[lhs:files_len])
        break
    for each in workers_list:  #for debug only
      print len(each)
    return workers_list
  
  def disassemble(self, objectfiles):
    for each_object in objectfiles:
      cmd = "{elfdump} -T {object} -o {lst}".format(
        elfdump=self.elfdumpExePath,
        object=each_object,
        lst=os.path.join(self.outputs, os.path.basename(each_object).rstrip('o') + 'lst'))
      p = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
  
  def execute(self):
    class FuncThread(threading.Thread):
      def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self._target = target
        self._args = args
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    
    workers = []
    for portion in self.slice(self.files):
      workers.append(FuncThread(self.disassemble, portion))

    # dispatch the workers
    for worker in workers:
      worker.start()
    
    # wait or join the previous dispatched workers
    for worker in workers:
      worker.join()
  
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  lst_gen = LstGenerator()
  lst_gen.execute()
```

**My Questions**

1. can i do this in more efficient way?
2. do python have standard lib or module that can get the job done and reduce my code/logic complexity? maybe `multiprocessing.Pool`?

running on windows, with python 2.7!

thanks

Comment: I wouldn't divide the list so early, but instead use a worker approach where each worker gets a new job as soon as the old one is done. This way you even out differences in parsing time between different files. (and there are libraries that help you do that)

Comment: Also check https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: `can i do this in more efficient way and more pythonic?` - switch to Python 3.8+

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html,

Comment: @bracco23 - thank you. can you mention these libs in your comment please (is joblib a standard lib?)

Comment: @wwii- i wish i could! unfortunatley i cant switch to py3. can use concurrent.futures in py2, i mean like `from future import concurrent.futures` ?

Comment: @Adam joblib is one of those libs and it is not standard, you'll have to do a quick pip install before using it (and i'm not sure it still works with python 2.7)

Comment: You picked a a wrong tool(Python) for parallelism

Comment: @overexchange - i know that python 2.x is not excellent in parallel scripts but they have improve this in py3. any other suggestions ?

Comment: @Adam improved? Pick a language that supports m:n threading model, for this situation. What is the need to pick Python for this? Multiprocessing is like over do, to hide the limitations of a language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting an answer for my question after strugling with it for a while, and noticing that i can import `concurrent.futures` in python2.x! this approach reduce code complexity ro minimum and even improve the execution time. unlike my first thoughts these processes is more IO-bound than cpu-bound! yet, the the time efficiency that i have get was enough convinient for run the program with multi-process.

---

`concurrent.futures`

> The concurrent.futures module provides a high-level interface for asynchronously executing callables.
> The asynchronous execution can be performed with threads, using
> ThreadPoolExecutor, or separate processes, using ProcessPoolExecutor.
> Both implement the same interface, which is defined by the abstract
> Executor class.

> `class concurrent.futures.Executor`
> An abstract class that provides
> methods to execute calls asynchronously. It should not be    used
> directly, but through its concrete subclasses.

`submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)`

> Schedules the callable, fn, to be executed as fn(*args **kwargs) and
> returns a Future object representing the execution of the callable.

for further reading please folow the like below:
[parallel tasks with concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

---

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import psutil
import threading
import os
import concurrent.futures

class LstGenerator(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.elfdumpExePath = r"C:\.....\elfdump.exe" #abs path to the executable 
    self.output_dir = r"C:\.....\out"             #abs path to where i want the lst files to be generated
    self.files = [] # assuming that i have all the files in this list (abs path for each .C file)
  
  def disassemble(self, objectfile):
    cmd = "{elfdump} -T {object} -o {lst}".format(
      elfdump=self.elfdumpExePath,
      object=objectfile,
      lst=os.path.join(self.outputs, os.path.basename(objectfile).rstrip('o') + 'lst'))
    return subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
  
  def execute(self):
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
      results = [executor.submit(self.disassemble(file)) for file in self.files]
  
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  lst_gen = LstGenerator()
  lst_gen.execute()
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction) can help with this. That also does the work of sharding the list of inputs for each CPU. Here is python code (untested) that should get you on your way.

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import subprocess

def convert(objectfile):
    elfdumpExePath = "C:\.....\elfdump.exe"
    output_dir = "C:\.....\out"

    cmd = "{elfdump} -T {obj} -o {lst}".format(
        elfdump=elfdumpExePath,
        obj=objectfile,
        lst=os.path.join(output_dir, os.path.basename(objectfile).rstrip('o') + 'lst'))
    return cmd

files = ["foo.c", "foo1.c", "foo2.c"]

p = multiprocessing.Pool()
outputs = p.map(convert, files)
```

Keep in mind that your worker function (`convert` above) must accept one argument. So if you need to pass in an input path and output path, that must be done as a single argument, and your list of filenames will have to be transformed into a list of pairs, where each pair is input and output.

The answer above is for python 2.7, but keep in mind that python2 has reached its end-of-life. In python3, you can use `multiprocessing.Pool` in a `with` statement so that it cleans up on its own.

Comment: thank you i will check this. im all my py scripts i did the multi threading and multiprocess my own. in your answer. all cpu core will utilized ? in other words iwill see activity on all of cpu cores ?

Comment: Yes, the `8` in `multiprocessing.Pool` means use 8 processes. If you leave it blank, it will use all available cores. And yes, you will see activity on all of your cores.

Comment: @Adam yes it should. Multiprocessing takes advantage of cross-processor programming, while the threading module is locked onto the same core due to the GIL lock.

Comment: @jakub - see my solution below.

Comment: @Adam - can be be more specific?

Comment: @jakub - getting     
with multiprocessing.Pool(8) as pool:
       AttributeError: "__exit__"    -> its dunder exit!

did you see my answer?

Comment: @Adam - see my updated answer. i didn't realize python2 did not have `multiprocessing.Pool` as a context manager.

Comment: @jakub-keep failing: see error message: "outputs = p.map(self.disassemble_t, self.fw_objects)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed"

Comment: @jakub - see my solution it works perfectly! what you think ?

Comment: @Adam - see my updated answer. you can compare yours to mine, but if they both work, then it's all up to you!